# Shiny: what is the difference between observeEvent and eventReactive?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, shiny-server

I read the Shiny documentation about reactive programming a few times now, but I can't properly understand the difference between `observeEvent` and `eventReactive`.

The documentation says:

> Use observeEvent whenever you want to perform an action in response to an event. (Note that "recalculate a value" does not generally count as performing an action–see eventReactive for that.)
>
> ....
>
> Use eventReactive to create a calculated value that only updates in response to an event. This is just like a normal reactive expression except it ignores all the usual invalidations that come from its reactive dependencies;

In all the situation I tried I saw no difference between using `observeEvent` and `eventReactive` (the code works just fine regardless the function I use, with no apparent impact in performances).

Can you help me figure out what is the real difference between the two? Ideally I would like a few examples showing when they are interchangeable, one when `observeEvent` would work but not `eventReactive` and vice versa.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As @daatali is saying the two functions are used for different purposes.

```
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("eventReactive and observeEvent"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("evReactiveButton", "eventReactive"),
    br(),
    actionButton("obsEventButton", "observeEvent"),
    br(),
    actionButton("evReactiveButton2", "eventReactive2")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("eText"),
    verbatimTextOutput("oText")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  etext <- eventReactive(input$evReactiveButton, {
    runif(1)
  })
  observeEvent(input$obsEventButton,{
    output$oText <- renderText({ runif(1) })
  })
  eventReactive(input$evReactiveButton2,{
    print("Will not print")
    output$oText <- renderText({ runif(1) })
  })
  output$eText <- renderText({
    etext()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

`eventReactive` creates a reactive value that changes based on the `eventExpr` while `observeEvent` simply is triggered based on `eventExpr`

Comment: fwiw Joe Cheng calls assigning an output from a render function from within an observer an "anti-solution" which "usually means the author has a fundamental misconception of what it means to assign a render code block to an output slot". I haven't fully grocked what this means. https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/192350_d3385f81117e4506a090da03ac8d3361.html#solution

Answer (score 58):

It's like the difference between `observe` and `reactive`. One is intended to be run when some reactive variable is "triggered" and is meant to have side effects (`observeEvent`), and the other returns a reactive value and is meant to be used as a variable (`eventReactive`).  Even in the documentation for those functions, the former is shown without being assigned to a variable (because it is intended to just produce a side effect), and the latter is shown to be assigned into a variable and used later on.

Comment: Is it possible to have a `reactiveValues` object "recieve" a `eventReactive`? From what I understand a `reactiveValues` is similar to a `reactive`, but I've only read examples of `observeEvent` dealing with them. Not sure if this comment is really in the scope of this thread... but if it's the case I can open a new one...

Comment: Excellent note about the variable storage.

Comment: What about creating a ‘reactiveVal’ , then populating it when an event triggers the ‘observeEvent’? Counter productive? Better to use ‘eventReactive’ because it’s lazy and not looping?

Answer (score 19):

I think the top level practical aspects need to be emphasized here.

- An `eventReactive` creates an object that *you* define like
  `reactive` does, but with out usual chain-reaction behavior you get
  from `reactive`. However it is lazily evaluated and cached like the
  other `reactives`.
- An `observeEvent` can not create an object that you define (it
  creates something else). It is immediately evaluated and not cached.
  It is for causing side-effects.

So if you need a data frame, or vector, or plot or something, but want to decouple from the usual reactive chain-reactions, use `eventReactive`.

If you just want to cause an immediate side effect, `observeEvent` is your ticket.

Answer (score 5):

Providing the way I understand this , correct me and add more information as required . Most of the information is from https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html

- Also may be this has been asked long ago, I had the same question while going through eventReactive() and observeEvent()
- ObeserveEvent , being more like a trigger for an event while eventReactive , being more like a delay
- Below I try the same code , using both the reactive functions

> To build several action buttons that control the same object, combine observeEvent() calls with reactiveValues() , Here I can use two actionButtons which are working at the same time in the same code.
>
> Code.1 Gives the effect of observeElement()
>
> Code.2 Uses eventReactive() , but if I try to use two different actionButtons, only the latest one works the earlier button is null and did not react

- Code 1

  ```
      library(shiny)

      ui<-fluidPage(
        actionButton("runif", "uniform"),
        actionButton("rnorm", "Normal"),
        hr(),
        plotOutput("plot")
      )

      server<-function(input, output){
        v<-reactiveValues(data=NULL)

        observeEvent(
          input$runif,
          {
          v$data<-runif(100)
          }
        )

        observeEvent(
          input$rnorm,
          {
          v$data<-rnorm(100)
          }
        )

        output$plot <- renderPlot(
          {
            if (is.null(v$data)) return()
            hist(v$data)
          }
        )
      }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
  ```
- code2

  ```
     library(shiny)

     ui<-fluidPage(
      actionButton(inputId = "norm", label = "Normal"),
      actionButton(inputId = "unif", label = "Uniform"),

    #Normal
    plotOutput("hist")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {

    dnorm <- eventReactive(input$norm, {rnorm(100)})
    dunif <- eventReactive(input$unif, {runif(100)})

    output$hist <- renderPlot({  
      hist(dfnorm())
    })

    output$hist <- renderPlot({  
      hist(dunif())
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
  ```

Comment: In code2, you have a typo: `hist(dfnorm())` instead of `hist(dnorm())`

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://riptutorial.com/shiny/example/32341/eventreactive) helpful for understanding `eventReactive`:

> eventReactives are similar to reactives, they are constructed as
> follows:
>
> ```
> eventReactive( event { 
> code to run 
> })
> ```
>
> eventReactives are not dependent on all reactive expressions in their body ('code to
> run' in the snippet above). Instead, they are only dependent on the
> expressions specified in the event section.