# Unexpected behavior Select All and Deselect All action buttons (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I encountered an unexpected behavior. What I intend to do is:
- when users click "Select All," all rows in "Summary Table" get selected. This WORKS. However, the code below doesn't get called.

```
data <- eventReactive(input$selectAll,{
      print("Select All - restore data")
      rawdata

  })
```

- on the other hand, when users click "Deselect All," all rows in "Summary Table" get deselected. This WORKS and the code below GETS called.

```
# Restore data when users click 'Deselect All'
  data <- eventReactive(input$deselectAll,{
      print("Deselect All - restore data")
      rawdata
  })
```

Any idea why?

Here is my full code:

DATASET

```
colA <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
colB <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
rawdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(colA,colB))
View(rawdata)
```

server.R

```
function(input, output, session) {

  # Activate tab 'Result' when users click 'Run'
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "allResults", 'result')
  })

  # Create a dataset based on users' selected variables
  data <- eventReactive(input$inputVars_rows_selected,{
      print("Select Some Vars")
      rawdata[, c(input$inputVars_rows_selected)]
  })

  # Restore data when users click 'Select All'
  data <- eventReactive(input$selectAll,{
      print("Select All - restore data")
      rawdata
  })

  # Restore data when users click 'Deselect All'
  data <- eventReactive(input$deselectAll,{
      print("Deselect All - restore data")
      rawdata
  })

  ### VARIABLE SELECTION ####

  var <- reactiveValues()

  # Select all vars
  observeEvent(input$selectAll,{
      print("SelectAll ObserveEvent")
      var$selected <- 1:nrow(rawdata)
      print(var$selected)
  })

  # Deselect all vars
  observeEvent(input$deselectAll,{
      print("deselectAll ObserveEvent")
      var$selected <- 0
      print(var$selected)
      print(data())
  })

  ### RESULT TAB ###

  result <- eventReactive (input$runButton, {
      head(data(),2)
  })

  ### RENDERING FUNCTIONS ###

  # Default SummaryTable
  output$inputVars <- DT::renderDataTable({
      if (input$selectAll==0 & input$deselectAll==0) {
          print("Default Summary Table")
          DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
      } 
      else {
          DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE), selection = list(target = 'row', selected = var$selected))
      }
  })

  # Display results
  output$result <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(result(), options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
  })

  output$temp <- renderPrint({
      print(input$selectAll)
      print(input$deselectAll)
  })
}
```

ui.R

```
fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("runButton", strong("Run!"))
  ),

  mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "allResults",
        tabPanel(value='inputVars',title='Variable Selection', 
                  verticalLayout(
                      DT::dataTableOutput('inputVars'),
                      br(),
                      fluidRow(align="bottom", 
                             column(2, actionButton("selectAll"  , strong("Select All"))),
                             column(3, actionButton("deselectAll", strong("Deselect All")))
                      )
                  )
                ),
        tabPanel(value='result',title='Result', DT::dataTableOutput('result')),
        tabPanel(value='temp',title="TEMP", verbatimTextOutput("temp"))
      )
  )

)
```

UPDATED Server.R #2: 
@Mike and @HubertL, I think you are right: the issue is caused by eventReactive having cached values. In this updated version, observeEvent corresponding to Select All and Deselect All work as expected. However, now eventReactive corresponding to input$inputVars_rows_selected NEVER gets called. Any idea why?

```
function(input, output, session) {

  # Activate tab 'Result' when users click 'Run'
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "allResults", 'result')
  })

  data <- reactiveValues()

  # Create a dataset based on users' selected variables
   data <- eventReactive(input$inputVars_rows_selected,{
       print("Select Some Vars")
       print(input$inputVars_rows_selected)
       rawdata[, c(input$inputVars_rows_selected)]
  })


  ### VARIABLE SELECTION ####

  var <- reactiveValues()

  # Select all vars
  observeEvent(input$selectAll,{
    print("SelectAll ObserveEvent")
    data <- rawdata
    var$selected <- 1:nrow(rawdata)
    print(var$selected)
    print(data)

  })

  # Deselect all vars
  observeEvent(input$deselectAll,{
    print("deselectAll ObserveEvent")
    data <- rawdata
    var$selected <- 0
    print(var$selected)
    print(data)

  })

  ### RESULT TAB ###

  result <- eventReactive (input$runButton, {
    head(data(),2)
  })

  ### RENDERING FUNCTIONS ###

  # Default SummaryTable
  output$inputVars <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (input$selectAll==0 & input$deselectAll==0) {
      print("Default Summary Table")
      DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
    } 
    else {
      DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE), selection = list(target = 'row', selected = var$selected))
    }
  })

  # Display results
  output$result <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(result(), options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
  })

  output$temp <- renderPrint({
    print(input$selectAll)
    print(input$deselectAll)
    print(input$inputVars_rows_selected)

  })
}
```

Comment: A name has one object : You cannot assign several reactive functions to a same variable name, only the last assignment is taken into account here. Consider making a single eventReactive function, and use if statements to return a different selection according to input

Comment: Oddly that does not seem to be true...

Comment: Probably is true actually, but hard to tell which `data()` is being pulled from because of `eventReactive` caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is because `eventReactive` is "lazily-evaluated" as opposed to `observeEvent` which is evaulated immediately.

So in your case the `observeEvent` corresponding to `deselectAll` actually uses `data()`, so that `reactiveEvent` gets triggered.

```
  # Deselect all vars
  observeEvent(input$deselectAll,{
    print("deselectAll ObserveEvent")
    var$selected <- 0
    print(var$selected)
    print(data())
  })
```

But the `observeEvent` corresponding to `selectAll` does not use `data()`, so that `reactiveEvent` does not get triggered:

```
  # Select all vars
  observeEvent(input$selectAll,{
    print("SelectAll ObserveEvent")
    var$selected <- 1:nrow(rawdata)
    print(var$selected)
  })
```

I suggest the following changes

- If you add a `print(data())` here you get *some* of the behavior you
  are seeking.
- But it is still not completely right because HubertL's comment that
  one definition of `data` is being overwritten is also valid - and
  note that it is not easy to tell where it the data is being pulled.
  This is because `eventReactive` have cached values, so your `print`
  may not show up if a cached value is being used - your code need be
  executed to pull that `data()`.
- So in any case I would certainly suggest using different names (and
  more descriptive) than just repeating "data" to avoid confusion.
- Also there is no need to use an `eventReactive` here, you probably
  want a simple `reactive`. `eventReactive` is usually needed if you
  want to avoid "reactions" from all the other reactive variables in
  the code, and I don't see a need for that here.
- I would also recommend putting `rawdata` into a `reactiveValues` something like this: `rv <- reactiveValues(rawdata=rawdata)` and then using it as `rv$rawdata`. This makes it reactive, and then something that uses it will be triggred and recomputed if it ever changes.

See this link [(observeEvent vs. eventReactive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519816/shiny-what-is-the-difference-between-observeevent-and-eventreactive) for a discussion of the "laziness" of those commands.

Comment: if I add "print(data())" in the observeEvent corresponding to selectAll, the reactiveEvent still does not get triggered.     I put my updated code in my original post. Thanks!

Comment: Oddly, I never got a notification of this comment. Just saw it now. I will have a look at it later this evening or tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that works. @Mike and @HubertL were right. The reason is because reactive is lazy vs observeEvent is not. Thanks all for your help!

```
function(input, output, session) {

  # Activate tab 'Result' when users click 'Run'
  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "allResults", 'result')
  })  

  data <- reactive({
     print("Select Some Vars")
     print(input$inputVars_rows_selected)
     rawdata[input$inputVars_rows_selected,]
  })

  ### VARIABLE SELECTION ####

  var <- reactiveValues()

  # Select all vars
  observeEvent(input$selectAll,{
    print("SelectAll --- ObserveEvent")
    var$selected <- 1:nrow(rawdata)
    print(var$selected)
    print(input$inputVars_rows_selected)
  })

  # Deselect all vars
  observeEvent(input$deselectAll,{
    print("deselectAll --- ObserveEvent")
    var$selected <- 0
    print(var$selected)
  })

  ### RESULT TAB ###

  result <- eventReactive (input$runButton, {
    head(data(),5)
  })

  ### RENDERING FUNCTIONS ###

  # Default SummaryTable
  output$inputVars <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (input$selectAll==0 & input$deselectAll==0) {
      print("Default Summary Table")
      DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
    } 
    else {
      DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE), selection = list(target = 'row', selected = var$selected))
    }
  })

  # Display results
  output$result <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(result(), options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
  })

  output$temp <- renderPrint({
    print(input$selectAll)
    print(input$deselectAll)
    print(input$inputVars_rows_selected)

  })
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Understanding how it works is a challenge.