# How to pass input values to the Bigquery in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, google-bigquery

I am trying to pass input values to a big query.

I tried passing reactive values and the input values directly. This works when we directly pass the vertical and kpi values.

```
 observeEvent(input$go, {
    vert_query <- input$vert
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    kpi_query <- input$kpi
  })

  alert_query <- reactive({
    gar_auth_service(
      json_file = " ",
      scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery")

    project <- "bigquery-project*" # put your project ID here


     sql <- paste0("SELECT Platform as Platform, Min(CPM) as Min_CPM, Max(CPM) as Max_CPM,  Avg(CPM) as Avg_CPM, Min(CPA) as Min_CPA, MAx(CPA) as Max_CPA, Avg(CPA) as Avg_CPA 
         FROM [bigquery-project*] where Vertical = ", input$vert," or KPI = ", input$kpi, 
              "Group BY Platform Order BY Platform")


    results <- bqr_query(projectId = project, query = sql, datasetId = "test")
    results
  })

  output$tbTable <- 
    renderTable({
      alert_query()
    })
```

I am expecting to see the query output in a table format

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you cannot assign a value using "`observeEvent`" and only works when you put it directly, maybe this can work: the code that you would need to use would be "`eventReactive`" instead "`observeEvent`", because "`observeEvent`" is used when you want to perform an action in response to an event and "`eventReactive`" creates a reactive value that changes based on the `eventExpr`, you can check this information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519816/shiny-what-is-the-difference-between-observeevent-and-eventreactive).