# How to show progress bar for computation in eventReactive()?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show a progress bar if something in `eventReactive()` is evaluated. 
However, `withProgress()` doesn't seem to work as expected if nothing is added directly to the output. (See the first part below that gets triggered by `input$go1`.)

In a dashboard with multiple panels it shows up if one navigates to another subpage. However, I want to 
have it showing up immediately after hitting the button.

Can anybody help to fix this problem in the example below?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
            actionButton("go1", "Go! Number 1"),
            actionButton("go2", "Go! Number 2"),
            plotOutput("plot")
            )



server <- function(input, output) {

    eventReactive(input$go1,{
        withProgress({
            for (i in 1:15) {
              incProgress(1/15)
              Sys.sleep(0.25)
              }
            }, message = "Doesn't show up!")
    })

output$plot <- renderPlot({
        input$go2
        withProgress({
            for (i in 1:15) {
                incProgress(1/15)
                Sys.sleep(0.1)
            }
        }, message = "Shows up!")
        plot(cars)
    })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: TBH, not entirely clear what you're asking. Perhaps, you missed to add `input$go1`  starting from a new line after `input$go2` in `output$plot`?:  
```output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$go2
    input$go1
    withProgress({
      for (i in 1:15) {
        incProgress(1/15)
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
      }
    }, message = "Shows up!")
    plot(cars)
  })
```

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan I want the progress bar in  `eventReactive()` to work. The second one is just there to show that it work when an output is produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eventReactive` isn't executed when the event expression is triggered, it is only flagged as invalidated. You'll have to request their reactive value to have them executed - please check the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go1", "Go! Number 1"),
  actionButton("go2", "Go! Number 2"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  myData <- eventReactive(input$go1, {
    withProgress({
      for (i in 1:15) {
        incProgress(1/15)
        Sys.sleep(0.25)
      }
    }, message = "Doesn't show up!")
    cars
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$go2
    req(myData())
    withProgress({
      for (i in 1:15) {
        incProgress(1/15)
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
      }
    }, message = "Shows up!")
    plot(myData())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For your example scenario `observeEvent` is the better choice. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519816/shiny-what-is-the-difference-between-observeevent-and-eventreactive).

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait. Actually my code should look as yours. I did a mistake in my reproducible example by forgetting the assignment. Since this seems to work perfectly my actual problem is probably related to `shinydashboard`. But thanks nontheless.

Comment: Feel free to adapt your example. Maybe we'll find a solution for your real problem.