# Plotting after Checking the radio Button and Pressing action Button

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe, please help me in executing this. The moment I check "HoltWinters" and press "Execute" button, dataframe "HW" should appear. I have tried half way. But need anyone help here please................................

```
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
library(fpp)
library("TTR")
```

```
x <- c(1:123)
x <- ts(x, start = c(2017, 23), end = c(2019, 39), frequency = 53)
x.hw <- HoltWinters(x)
HW <- forecast(x.hw, h = 6)
HW <- as.data.frame(HW)
```

Model Execution

`Inputs {.sidebar}`

```
radioButtons("r",h5("Models"),choices = list("Regression", "Arima","HoltWinters","Model4","Model5"),selected = "No", inline = F)
actionButton("a","Execute",icon = NULL)
```

`Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}`

HoltWinters

```
output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
  eventReactive(input$a,{
    rhandsontable(HW)
  })
})
rHandsontableOutput("table1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `eventReactive` but `observeEvent` instead (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519816/shiny-what-is-the-difference-between-observeevent-and-eventreactive)). Also, this condition should be outside of the `output` part: "if I observe this event, then I will display this table" (and not "I will display this table and then fill it according to which button is ticked").

Here's the solution to your problem (you should customize it so that just selecting HoltWinters displays the table but at least you have a working basis here):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
library(fpp)
library(TTR)
```

```{r}
x <- c(1:123)
x <- ts(x, start = c(2017, 23), end = c(2019, 39), frequency = 53)
x.hw <- HoltWinters(x)
HW <- forecast(x.hw, h = 6)
HW <- as.data.frame(HW)
```

Model Execution
=================

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}
radioButtons("r",h5("Models"),choices = list("Regression", "Arima","HoltWinters","Model4","Model5"),selected = "No", inline = F)
actionButton("a","Execute",icon = NULL)
```


Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### HoltWinters

```{r}
observeEvent(input$a,{
  output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
     rhandsontable(HW)
    })
})
rHandsontableOutput("table1")
```
````

**Edit:** you can add a condition within the `observeEvent` so that the table is displayed only if HoltWinters is ticked:

```
observeEvent(input$a,{
  if (input$r == "HoltWinters") {
    output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
      rhandsontable(HW)
    })
  }
  else {
    output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    })
  }
})
rHandsontableOutput("table1")
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly. I am not able to customise this that is  just selecting HoltWinters should displays the table. Please help

Comment: happy to help :)