# Is there a way to check multiple boxes at once using checkboxgroupinput widget?

Tags: r, shiny

First thanks in advance for providing any insight into the problem I am experiencing now.

I am using checkboxgroupinput widget to develop a simple kmeans clustering app that allows users to choose their own features. There is a slight annoyance that I want to solve: the kmeans algorithm runs every time you check (or uncheck) a feature. For example, if one chooses feature A B and C, the model will 3 times, first A only, then A and B and then A, B and C; if the users wants to try D, E, and F, then the model runs 6 more times (unchecking A B and C one by one, then repeat for D, E and F).

Thanks again.

Is there a way to just run the model twice, first A, B and C as a list and then D, E and F as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an action button, after a selecting the features, users need to click a button that you can manage by 'eventReactive' or 'observeEvent' for running your model. you could use shinyWidgets::actionBttn or [shiny::actionButton](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html) I found [an example for observeEvent vs. eventReactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519816/shiny-what-is-the-difference-between-observeevent-and-eventreactive)